# How do I format a number to a dollar amount in PHP

Tags: php, formatting, currency

How do you convert a number to a string showing dollars and cents?

```
eg:
123.45    => '$123.45'
123.456   => '$123.46'
123       => '$123.00'
.13       => '$0.13'
.1        => '$0.10'
0         => '$0.00'
```

Comment: Do you have a specific programming language in mind?

Comment: I suppose it should be specific - I'll change it now.

Comment: Be careful with the implicit rounding introduced by formatting floating point to a certain digit. If there are two items with $0.015, you can have situations where 2 + 2 = 3. Also note that floating point does not hold simple values like 0.1 accurately.

Comment: You should use integers and store number of cents, rather than using floating points, otherwise you will lose some cents along the way.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

PHP also has [money_format()](http://php.net/money_format).

Here's an example:

```
echo money_format('$%i', 3.4); // echos '$3.40'
```

This function actually has tons of options, go to the documentation I linked to to see them.

Note: money_format is undefined in Windows.

---

UPDATE: Via the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

*WARNING: This function [**money_format**] has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.*

Instead, look into [NumberFormatter::formatCurrency](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php).

```
    $number = "123.45";
    $formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    return $formatter->formatCurrency($number, 'USD');
```

Comment: From the doco:
Note: The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

Comment: I like this approach best in theory, but why does mine output **$USD 3.40**. Would you know what params I can change to get the output above (without the "USD")? Obviously I'd prefer to do this without str_replace or regexes.

Comment: Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9761657/2426945). Just do _money_format('%.2n', 3.4);_

Comment: Is this function now deprecated?  When I use it it's now 'undefined'.

Comment: But `money_format('$%i', 3.4)` does not handle negatives the way most people would prefer.

Comment: The money_format() function is deprecated. It can be replaced by the intl NumberFormatter functionality. Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php

Answer (score 90):

If you just want something simple:

```
'$' . number_format($money, 2);
```

[number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)

Comment: be aware that this will add a comma (or the equivalent in your locale) after each grouping of three digits. this might be desired, but could be very confusing if you weren't expecting it.

Comment: To do it without thousands separators: `'$' . number_format($money, 2, '.', '');`

Comment: this doesn't work for negative numbers, we use -$69.42 not $-69.42

Answer (score 17):

i tried  `money_format()` but it didn't work for me at all. then i tried the following one. it worked perfect for me. hopefully it will work in right way for you too.. :)

you should use this one

```
number_format($money, 2,'.', ',')
```

it will show money number in terms of money format up to 2 decimal.

Answer (score 9):

Note that in PHP 7.4, money_format() function is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php). It can be replaced by the intl NumberFormatter functionality, just make sure you enable the php-intl extension. It's a small amount of effort and worth it as you get a lot of customizability.

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$f->formatCurrency(12345, "USD"); // Outputs "$12,345.00"
```

The fast way that will still work for 7.4 is as mentioned by [Darryl Hein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5441/darryl-hein):

```
'$' . number_format($money, 2);
```

Comment: My PHP was missing the `Intl` extension, so this got me on the right track!

Answer (score 8):

In PHP and C++ you can use the printf() function

```
printf("$%01.2f", $money);
```

Comment: The built in PHP functions are really handy.

Answer (score 2):

In php.ini add this (if it is missing):

```
#windows
extension=php_intl.dll

#linux
extension=php_intl.so
```

Then do this:

```
$amount = 123.456;

// for Canadian Dollars
$currency = 'CAD';

// for Canadian English
$locale = 'en_CA';

$fmt = new \NumberFormatter( $locale, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency($amount, $currency);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*     Just Do the following, */

echo money_format("%(#10n","123.45"); //Output $ 123.45

/*    If Negative Number -123.45 */

echo money_format("%(#10n","-123.45"); //Output ($ 123.45)
```