# Format a money field in SQL without converting to varchar?

Tags: sql, formatting, currency

I need to be able to display a money field as $XX,XXX.XX, but without converting to varchar using `total_eval = '$' + CONVERT(varchar(19),total_eval.opvValueMoney,1)`

My project uses sorting of the information after I pull this to sort the column and it doesn't sort correctly when the column is a varchar.

Is there anyway to do this?

This is part of an ASP.NET system, but I have no access or control over after the information is returned.

Comment: there's no way to put a , or $ in a number without making it a varchar. those characters are not part of a number, they're part of a string.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what languages and platforms you're using? Would be better to know who is giving the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not format this when the data is being printed on the screen? Then the number remains a number and you can format is as you please at the presentation level.

For example, using PHP you could do something like this:

```
echo money_format('$%i', 3.4); // echos '$3.40'
//                       ^ here is your number, no formatting from the db!
```

This example was found in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294865/how-do-i-format-a-number-to-a-dollar-amount-in-php).