# money_format() options

Tags: php, currency

I am looking at the money_format function in php and confused on how to get it to format the way I want. I do not want USD in front of my string, I want a comma every 3 digits and 2 decimal points so 12345.67 will be formated to $12,345.67

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you looked at `number_format`? It's a little easier I think.

`print number_format( 1234567, 2, ",", "." );` for example.

Comment: Agreed, I honestly don't know why they even created `money_format()`, it's like a foreign language.

Comment: It's a wrapper for C's `strfmon` function. It's just one of those little things that give PHP a easy learning curve for developers who are used to other languages (and their default functionality). It actually can be quite useful for formatting currency for plain-text situations where you want to align (like str_pad could do)

Comment: Thanks, I had to switch the placement of the `,` and `.` params to make it US instead of EURO style.

Comment: Good answer CharlesLeaf. The money_format has proven itself useless to me when compared to this lol.

Answer (score 18):

To answer the original question using `money_format`, it's simply

```
money_format('%.2n', 12345.67);
```

`money_format` always starts with a `%`. The `.2` indicates you want to always use 2 decimal places. If you pass a whole number it will add .00 to the end. The `n` indicates you want use the locale's national currency format.

It's important to note that you must have the locale set correctly since money_format is based on the locale you have set for `LC_MONETARY`. To set the locale use `setlocale`. In this case it appears you want `en_US`.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

Comment: For US it's actually en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Don't know why but the manual states the proper way is to drop the hyphen so it should read "en_US.UTF8" it may be different php versions this is php 7.##