# Money format in Laravel - 100 to $1.00

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How do I change the last 2 digits of a number to cents in dollar value using Laravel?

For example:

```
100 = 1.00
149 = 1.49
100034 = 1,000.34
```

Comment: You could divide by 100?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a number to a dollar amount in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294865/how-do-i-format-a-number-to-a-dollar-amount-in-php)

Comment: @iainn nope, I don't want to use a '.' in the database - I want the cents to always be the last 2 numbers in the field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Example:

```
function pretty_print($number) {
  return number_format($number / 100, 2);
}

echo pretty_print(100);
echo pretty_print(149);
echo pretty_print(100034);
```

Result:

```
1.00
1.49
1,000.34
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$digit = 123456;
echo number_format($digit/100,2);
```

Output:

```
1234.56
```